# Is it possible to get the matched regex from within the apache LocationMatch directive?

Tags: apache-2.2, regex

I'm wondering if the following code should be working:

```
<LocationMatch "/(.*)([/])?(.*)">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git"
    AuthUserFile  /git/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /git/.htgroup
    Require group $1
</LocationMatch>
```

What I am trying to achieve with this is to require a group based on the first regex variable. So if the user goes to `http://localhost/a-repository-name` he has to be in the group `a-repository-name` to be able to open the url.

For some reason I can't get this code working and apache returns:
`Authorization of user **** to access /a-repository-name failed, reason: user is not part of the 'require'ed group(s).`
I guess it's not matching against the proper variable at `Require group $1`.
 
Is this the right way to be done or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LocationMatch` doesn't support backreferencing, you can't do that in versions before 2.4.8.

Comment: Can you please provide a link in the documentation where this is stated? I changed `Require group $1` to `Require group mygroup` and it worked perfect.

Comment: @tftd: Changed the wording. I meant regexp grouping, not the group you set in `Require`.

Comment: Is there any known workaround?

Comment: @tftd: I'm afraid you'll have to attack the problem from another angle.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch) this is now supported...

> From 2.4.8 onwards, named groups and backreferences are captured and written to the environment with the corresponding name prefixed with "MATCH_" and in upper case. This allows elements of URLs to be referenced from within expressions and modules like mod_rewrite. In order to prevent confusion, numbered (unnamed) backreferences are ignored. Use named groups instead.

```
<LocationMatch "^/combined/(?<sitename>[^/]+)">
    require ldap-group cn=%{env:MATCH_SITENAME},ou=combined,o=Example
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for answering such an old question! I'm glad they've included this in the newer versions. Unfortunately I can't accept your answer because the original answer was valid at the time.

Comment: Does this work? I tried something similar https://serverfault.com/questions/844571/proxypassmatch-environment-variable-usage and i cant get it to work